# Hosting a SharePoint Page in a minimalist manner

Tags: 2013, csom, app

I have a simple SharePoint CSOM page that is used to pull the Current user and their Email. I'm hosting this page in a dedicated Site Collection which seems like overkill. It's essentially a redirect page and I'd like to host this page without the need for a Front End. ie, no Master Page or CSS or necessary javaScript loads.

Can CSOM code be hosted in, say, a HTML page if it's on the Server and loads sp.js? How could I run this code in the most minimalist way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two minimalist ways to run code in SharePoint:

1. Create an ASP.NET web application and put your code in Default.aspx.cs. Deploy manually to the 15 Hive in a _layouts subfolder. Then access in the browser via http://any_site_collection/_layouts/15/subfolder/Default.aspx
2. Rewrite your code and use JavaScript only. To host it in SharePoint, a simple and efficient way is to put the code in an HTML file in Style Library and use Content Editor web part with link to the HTML file.